# How to deploy vmview from a single esx server

Tags: vmware-esx, deployment, vmware-vsphere, vmware-player

I am beginner in vmware and virualization and need some assistance. 
I have a good web server with 22 GB Ram memory and I need to deploy vmware view from this single host if it is possible. I need some guidance how to make this, shall I use vmware server free product? What exactly can I do with a single server and how many VM's can I deploy in that machine with VMware Server? Or shall I use only vmware view from VMware Player only installed on that machine (confused because of no experience)?

I am sorry for such questions but I need only some advice for starting with that single machine and install let say 2-3 OS (different vms). And if its possible to access them from vmware view, or what possibility I can get.

Comment: I think you may be a little out of your league here. When you say you have a "good web server" is this a VPS or something similar? I think you should take a look at the different flavours of ESX/ESXi and see which ones would be best for you. Do you even need VMWare, if you're just running two or three VMs would VirtualBox not be better?

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer, but If I user VBox shall I use vmware view, my goal is using vmware view from an ipad, I repeat I have that single server, and my plan is to deploy 2-3 vm at max...

Comment: Lain this was good answer ;) already described above...

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. VirtualBox is a free virtulisation package from Oracle so will not be compatible with the VMWare View (as far as I know, anyway). Try it with the free VMWare package and see how well the server performs. It would all be down t the disk I/O, the processer and the RAM capacity. As for VMWare View I've never heard of it.

Comment: thank you once again tombull, but my goal is using let say a free tool vmware player, where I'll install 2-3 vm with different os, then I need to access these vm from that server via iPad, it is possible this from an vmware player with isntalled vms already, and not having any vmware view composer, manager...so simply I need to run different vms from an iPad from that single server, how to do this...so which tool shall I use for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we're clear, VMware View is used for [Desktop Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization) management and it's best if you're doing a lot of desktop clients (to the point where you will want more than one server).  If you just need remote control capabilities to a VM, I would recommend something like [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) to control a VM across the Internet or your inside your network or [Wyse Pocket Cloud](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wyse-pocketcloud-pro-rdp-vnc/id326512817?mt=8) if you want to control a Windows VM inside your network.

I would recommend you start by using [Hypervisor](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/overview.html) from VMware and then use their [documentation on VMware View](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/view_pubs.html) to get your legs under you.

Let me know if you have any follow up questions because your question is really hard to follow.

Comment: This answer gives me a better direction, so what's the difference between using Hypervisor and vmware player on a single machine, which one is more useful for my case (suppose I'll access remotely via iPad within wyse pocket), so which tool to install on that machine and why?

Comment: Hypervisor (VMware product) is a type 1 hypervisor (generic term) so it runs on the "bare metal" in lieu of an OS so if you already have an OS installed it will have to be reinstalled or converted to a VM.  It's a good use of a large VM hosts because it can better manage the memory, network access, and CPU and you don't have to worry about the Host OS crashing.  VMware Player is used for running VMs inside another OS and if I remember correctly, (I haven't used it) it doesn't allow you to create a new VM or edit them once they are created.